# i want to sum date in a looping 13 times using pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, pyspark-pandas

Please help me to solve this issue, as I am still new to Python/Pyspark.
I want to do a loop to do a date sum in multiples of 7 for 13 times in the same column.

I have a master table like this :

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-02-21 10:00:00 |
| 2 | 2019-02-27 09:50:33 |

*etc*

I have created a script but wrong, instead created a new column, even though I want to create a new column..

I want this kind of result :

| id | x | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 2019-02-21 |
| 1 | 14 | 2019-02-28 |
| 1 | 21 | 2019-03-14 |
| 1 | 28 | 2019-03-21 |
| 1 | 35 | 2019-03-28 |
| 1 | 42 | 2019-04-04 |
| 1 | 49 | 2019-04-11 |
| 1 | 56 | 2019-04-18 |
| 1 | 63 | 2019-04-25 |
| 1 | 70 | 2019-05-02 |
| 1 | 77 | 2019-05-09 |
| 1 | 84 | 2019-05-16 |
| 1 | 91 | 2019-05-16 |

*etc*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`sequence`** function and then **`explode`**.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1','2019-02-21 10:00:00'),('2','2019-02-27 09:50:33')],['id','date']).\
  withColumn("seq", expr("""sequence(0,91,7)""")).\
    withColumn("date", to_date(col("date")))
df = df.select("id","date",explode(col("seq")))
df.withColumn("date", expr("""date_add(date, col)""")).show(200, False)

#+---+----------+---+
#|id |date      |col|
#+---+----------+---+
#|1  |2019-02-21|0  |
#|1  |2019-02-28|7  |
#|1  |2019-03-07|14 |
#|1  |2019-03-14|21 |
#|1  |2019-03-21|28 |
#|1  |2019-03-28|35 |
#|1  |2019-04-04|42 |
#|1  |2019-04-11|49 |
#|1  |2019-04-18|56 |
#|1  |2019-04-25|63 |
#|1  |2019-05-02|70 |
#|1  |2019-05-09|77 |
#|1  |2019-05-16|84 |
#|1  |2019-05-23|91 |
#|2  |2019-02-27|0  |
#|2  |2019-03-06|7  |
#|2  |2019-03-13|14 |
#|2  |2019-03-20|21 |
#|2  |2019-03-27|28 |
#|2  |2019-04-03|35 |
#|2  |2019-04-10|42 |
#|2  |2019-04-17|49 |
#|2  |2019-04-24|56 |
#|2  |2019-05-01|63 |
#|2  |2019-05-08|70 |
#|2  |2019-05-15|77 |
#|2  |2019-05-22|84 |
#|2  |2019-05-29|91 |
#+---+----------+---+
```

Comment: Can Col '0' be replaced with '7' and so on and for last col in '98' is droped?

Comment: Yes, u can try it.. based on your `expected output` I have given 0 as a start position for the sequence..!